# Regular expression to match numbers, finite ranges, and infinite ranges (such as >=9)

Tags: javascript, regex

What can be a regular expression for following type of string

E.g. 1, 2-3, 4..5, <6, <=7, >8, >=9
Here I am using equals, range (-), sequence (..) & greater than/equal to operators for numbers less than 100. These numbers are separated by a comma.

Pls help me in writing a regular expression for this. Thanks in advance.

- Atul

Comment: For what? What do you want to match?!

Comment: What do you want to match and in which language

Comment: I am using ExtJS. One of the textfield made with ExtJS component should allow comma separated number/opeator strings like

1, 2-3, 4..5, <6, <=7, >8, >=9

So the regex should allow combination of this type of comma separated string.

- Atul

Comment: use a regular expression tool like regex buddy or expresso.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... 

I tried with the regular expression provided by dlamblin. It is working perfect for all pattern except:

1. Only if relationship operators (<, <=, >, >=) are present as first element of the string. E.g. <=3, 4-5, 6, 7..8  ---> works perfect, but  <=3, 4-5, 6, 7..8, >=5  --->  relationship operator not at 1st element of string.

2. Also string <3<4, 5, 9-4 doesnot give any error i.e. it is satisfying condition though comma is needed between <3 & <4

3. Numbers in the string should be less than or equal to 100.
i.e. <100, 0-100, 99..100

Thanks in advance.
Atul

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
^(\d+(-|\.\.)|[<>]=?)?\d+$
```

Example using Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '^(\d+(-|\.\.)|[<>]=?)?\d+$'
>>> for s in '1, 2-3, 4..5, <6, <=7, >8, >=9'.split(','):
...     print(re.match(pattern, s.strip()).group(0))
... 
1
2-3
4..5
<6
<=7
>8
>=9
```

To be clear, this regex matches only *one* element in the list. I **highly recommend** that you *preprocess* your input by splitting it on commas and trimming the individual elements, like I did in the example above. Even though that's not strictly necessary (you *can* add this logic to the regex I gave here), it will but quite a bit more efficient and readable.

**How the regex works:**

- Observe that every valid string ends with one or more digits, thus `\d+$`.
- There may or may not be something before that, thus, `^(...)?\d+$`.
- Those prefixes are either the start of a range, or a comparison:

  - `\d+(-|\.\.)` matches a number followed by a dash or two periods.
  - `<=?` matches `"<"` as well as `"<="`. Likewise for `>=?`. We can abbreviate this to `[<>]=?`.
- Combining these two options using a pipe (`|`), which signifies choice, we get

  ```
  ^(\d+(-|\.\.)|[<>]=?)?\d+$
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
^(?:\d+(?:(?:\.\.|-)\d+)?|[<>]=?\d+)(?:,\s*\d+(?:(?:\.\.|-)\d+)?|[<>]=?\d+)*$
```

It consists of the alternation of

- `\d+(?:(?:\.\.|-)\d+)?` for a number followed by an optional expression for a range or sequence, and
- `[<>]=?\d+` for the inequalities.

That’s repeated in the second parts with a comma and optional whitespace for the list.

And for the condition of only allowing numbers less than 100, you can replace `\d+` with `[1-9]\d` for 1..99 or `(?:0|[1-9]\d)` for 0..99.

Answer (score 0):

You should totally use a regular expression tool like regex buddy.

You're trying to verify that your string generally looks like the sample?

```
1, 2-3, 4..5, <6, <=7, >8, >=9
```

matches

```
\s*(\d+|\d+-\d+|\d+\.\.\d+|[<>]=?\d+)\s*(,\s*(\d+|\d+-\d+|\d+\.\.\d+|[<>]=?\d+)\s*)*
```

It's easier to split on `,` and then match each part with

```
\s*(\d+|\d+-\d+|\d+\.\.\d+|[<>]=?\d+)\s*
```

That reads:
white space trimmed, match digits or digits dash digits, or digits dot dot digits, or one of less-than or greater-than with optional equal to digits.

You can compress that down to the harder to read:

```
\s*((\d+(-|\.\.)|[<>]=?)?\d+)\s*
```

If you want all your digits to be 1-2 digits only, then change all the `\d+` to `\d{1,2}` or `\d\d?`